# How to re-order columns in Bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm fairly new to bootstrap and I have been having trouble re-ordering columns when re-sized in mobile.

So far this is what I have tried:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-5 order-lg-1">
        B
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-5">
      <div class="col-lg-12 order-lg-0">
        A
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-12 order-lg-2">
        C
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
</div>
```

What I wanted to achieve is something like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wPO6.jpg

And when I run my code and resized in mobile it turns out like this:
B
A
C

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Can you show CSS for order-lg-x classes? Or create a stackblitz?

Comment: Unfortunately no, but I solved it using bootstrap's hiding elements. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Bootstrap [Hidding Element](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/display/#hiding-elements) option and also use [Grid System](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/layout/grid/) to apply on mobile device col-sm* or col-xs* .
Other option is to use [Media Query](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) to apply classes depending of the device width and height.

Example based on your code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 order-md-2 order-lg-2 d-md-block d-sm-none d-xs-none d-none">
            B
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
          <div class="col-lg-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 order-lg-1">
            A
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 order-lg-2 d-block d-sm-none d-md-none">
            B
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 order-lg-3">
            C
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I did try using the hiding elements and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply make the columns like this.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        A
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        C
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        B
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```